# Create text wrap and manage column width with Datatable in Shiny

Tags: shiny, datatables, dt

I have a data table that has a lot of written text. I would like to organize this in an easy to read way. I have tried a few ideas but they do not seem to work. I am also open to any advice on how I should be organizing the data table.

Here is my code I am trying to control the width of the columns. Right now the width are extremely wide and i would like to narrow selected columns quite a bit.

```
output$newsfeed = renderDataTable({
  datatable(df, rownames = F, extensions = "Scroller", 
          options = list(deferRender = TRUE,
                         scrollY = 400,
                         scrollX = TRUE,
                         scroller = TRUE,
                         autoWidth = TRUE,
                         columnDefs = list(list(width = '50px', targets = list(1,2,3,4,5)))
                                                                       
  ))
})
```

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `width = '10%'` for the columns of interest.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "B"),
  V2 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in New York"
  ),
  V3 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in New Jersey"
  ),
  V4 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in California"
  ),
  V5 = c(
    "A cool guy living in the US and else where", 
    "A cool guy living in Texas"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, options = list(
      deferRender = TRUE,
      scrollY = 400,
      scrollX = TRUE,
      scroller = TRUE,
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '10%', targets = c(2,3,4)))
    ))  # %>% formatStyle(columns = c(2,3), width='20px')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: for some reason this works for me outside my shiny app. However, inside my shiny app, it does not work. I am using bsDash4 instead of shinydashboard. Do you think that could be the reason?

Comment: In that case, please try `sScrollXInner  = "80%"` as an option.  It will reduced the width of all columns.  Try different percentages and figure out which fits your needs.

Comment: @YBS It works when the text is space separated as created by you. However, if the column has long text separated by only comma without anyspaces, then this is not working. Im now in a similar need where the column has text separated by commas and it is not working as in the example. Could u help?

Comment: @chas, Please post it as a new question, and then someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 'extensions = "Scroller"' conflicts controlling column width.
When I add 'extensions = "Scroller"' to YBS's code then texts is not wrapped.